# Upload laravel project + inertia react to cpanel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I made a website using laravel 10 and inertia react js.

This page isn’t working.
subdomain.myDomain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

And now I want to host this on Cpanel but I'm facing a problem.
I put the project in public_html and modified the urls in index.php.
[![If I put some text in index.php it works..]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBTve.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBTve.png)

Answer (score 0):

and i solved my problem.
I had problem with builds in the public/build directory I needed to run (npm run dev) But now I ran (npm run build) locally and copied the build directory from local to the server and it is working. I want to know if it is a good way to run the build?
If there is another solution
please tell me......